# If you are missing some letters of a word, how to determine which word it is?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, complexity-theory, neural-network

Say you are writing an OST, or a networking error correction application. So you are dealing with a word with some letters missing, say, "*leph*nt". You have the english dictionary stored in an array. How do you determine which word is it?

Comment: Please define "OST" in this context.

Comment: Do you know which letters are missing?  Or are you just given the characters you received in the order in which you received them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computing Levenstein distance between your query and all dictionary words will certainly be slow.

A better strategy is used by the [BLAST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST) program for biological sequences. In BLAST, an index is first built a database of sequences that associates substrings of small, fixed length, K, with a list of all of the words that contain them.

On a query, BLAST searches the index for all K-length substrings from the query string. The matching substrings across the query and index strings can then be extended to quickly compute an approximate Levenstein distance, and the index strings with a distance below some threshold are returned.

Answer (score 5):

A common approach is to use the closest word as measured by the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Ties can be resolved arbitrarily and a maximum allowed distance is usually used.

Comment: But then you'd have to check it against every word on the dictionary? That will take a long time.

Comment: @Dokkat - Not necessarily. For instance, you don't have to look at dictionary words that differ in length by more than the maximum distance from the sample word. Things can be sped up dramatically with clever dictionary indexing and the use of dynamic programming. See the [Wikipedia article _Approximate string matching_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) for more info and links to resources.